# Calculate area of polygon having WGS coordinates using DotSpatial?

Tags: c#, area, dotspatial

Calculating area:

```
var coordinates = new List<Coordinate> {
    new Coordinate(55, 35),
    new Coordinate(55, 35.1),
    new Coordinate(55.1, 35.1),
    new Coordinate(55.1, 35),
};
Console.WriteLine(new Polygon(coordinates).Area); // ~0.01
```

Calculation is right, because it's happen in orthogonal coordinate system.

But how to mark that coordinates are in WGS?

Comment: What is WGS????

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System

Answer (score 3):

It seems that task is more complicated that I've expected. I found this useful discussion on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nettopologysuite/gl2g2O807X0)

Firstly we need to found projection system, that is most suitable for our region where we need to compute area. For example you can take one of [UTM zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)

```
using DotSpatial.Projections;
using DotSpatial.Topology;
public static double CalculateArea(IEnumerable<double> latLonPoints)
{
    // source projection is WGS1984
    var projFrom = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;
    // most complicated problem - you have to find most suitable projection
    var projTo = KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.UtmWgs1984.WGS1984UTMZone37N;

    // prepare for ReprojectPoints (it mutates array)
    var z = new double[latLonPoints.Count() / 2];
    var pointsArray = latLonPoints.ToArray();

    Reproject.ReprojectPoints(pointsArray, z, projFrom, projTo, 0, pointsArray.Length / 2);

    // assemblying new points array to create polygon
    var points = new List<Coordinate>(pointsArray.Length / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsArray.Length / 2; i++)
        points.Add(new Coordinate(pointsArray[i * 2], pointsArray[i * 2 + 1]));

    var poly = new Polygon(points);
    return poly.Area;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the area directly from IGeometry or from Feature.Geometry. Also You need to repeat the first coordinate to close your polygon.

```
FeatureSet fs = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Polygon);

Coordinate[] coord = new Coordinate[]
{
    new Coordinate(55, 35),
    new Coordinate(55, 35.1),
    new Coordinate(55.1, 35.1),
    new Coordinate(55.1, 35),
    new Coordinate(55, 35)
};

fs.AddFeature(new Polygon(new LinearRing(coord)));

var area = fs.Features.First().Geometry.Area;
```

Comment: little late but hope it helps to someone else